# How to retrive a list of the most recent entry in a table of each 'player'

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This is similar to the table I have:

```
+-----------+--------+
| Player id | Score  |
+-----------+--------+
|  User 1   |   10   |
|  User 2   |   22   | 
|  User 1   |   17   |
|  User 3   |   34   |
|  User 4   |   23   |
|  User 2   |   12   |
|  User 3   |   10   |
|  User 4   |   30   |
+-----------+--------+
```

I also have a timestamp on each row.

What is the best way to get the most recent row for each 'player'. like the following result:

```
+-----------+--------+
| Player id | Score  |
+-----------+--------+
|  User 1   |   10   |
|  User 2   |   22   | 
|  User 3   |   34   |
|  User 4   |   23   |
+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT Player_id, 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY date_added DESC),',',1) AS recent_score,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(date_added ORDER BY date_added DESC),',',1) AS recent_date
  FROM table
 GROUP BY Player_id
```

Here I have assumed your timestamp field as date_added, and also score by recent date

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a query like this:
(`time field` is your timestamp field that elaborate recent record)

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`Player id`, `t1`.`Score`, `t1`.`time field`
FROM `yourTable` As `t1`
    JOIN
    `yourTable` As `t2` 
    ON `t1`.`Player id` = `t2`.`Player id`
    AND `t1`.`time field` <= `t2`.`time field`
GROUP BY
    `t1`.`Player id`, `t1`.`Score`, `t1`.`time field`
HAVING 
    COUNT(`t2`.`Player id`) = 1;
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c44d9/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```
SELECT
    <Player_id>, <Score>
FROM
    <your_table>
WHERE
    (<clientID>,<timestamp>) IN (
        SELECT
            <Player_id>, MAX(<timestamp>)
        FROM
            <your_table>
        GROUP BY
            <Player_id>
    );
```

Just replace the `<enclosed>` part with the corresponding column name of your table.